# How to convert a sequence of integers into a monomial

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm writing a paper that have many expressions of the form

```
$$x^3 y^2 x^{-1} y x^2 y^5$$
```

Both the length and the exponents could change from one instance to another.

**Is it possible to create a macro, call it `\xy`, such that**

```
\xy{3,2,-1,1,2,5}
```

**would give the word above, and**

```
\xy{-1,7,4}
```

**would give**

```
$$x^{-1} y^7 x^4$$
```

Note:

- Every exponent is non-zero (otherwise we just combine the adjacent terms)
- It is okay to have two commands `\xyodd` and `\xyeven` depending on the parity of the length of the word
- It is okay to have two versions, one with the word starting with x, and another, with y
- If an exponent is 1, ideally it would just print the variable instead of e.g. `x^1`, but that's a minor issue.
- It is okay for the command to have two inputs, one for the length of the word, and another, for the list of exponents.

For example

```
\xynew{ 6, {3,2,-1,1,2,5} }
```

would give

```
$$x^3 y^2 x^{-1} y x^2 y^5$$
```

while

```
\xynew{ 3, {-1,7,4} }
```

would give

```
$$x^{-1} y^7 x^4$$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% initialise variable to x and add a `\relax` marker for the end
\def\xy#1{\def\xya{x}\xxy#1,\relax,}

% grab one term
\def\xxy#1,{%
% if \relax, stop
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
% print the varable
\xya
% add superscript if not 1
\ifnum#1=1 \else^{#1}\fi
% flip definition between x and y
\edef\xya{\if\xya x y\else x\fi}%
% jump past closing \fi, and grab next item
\expandafter\xxy
\fi}

\begin{document}

\[
\xy{3,2,-1,1,2,5}
\]
\[
\xy{-1,7,4}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Carlisle:  Totally brilliant, thanks so much!  Two follow-up questions: (1) Care to give a brief explanation of how your macro work?  I know latex but not plain tex.  (2) Is there a reason why $$  $$ in my original post did not get processed? Thanks!

Comment: @underflow we don't use mathjax on this site. (mathjax is a good thing but it doesn't use tex, and mostly we need to see tex output)

Comment: @underflow comments added

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun...

[image]

Here is the API proposed.

```
\begin{document}

\section{Default use}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6} \]

\[ \xy{3,2,1,1,2,3} \]

\[ \xy{-1,-2,-3} \]

\[ \xy{1,2} \]

\[ \xy{12345} \]

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} \]


\section{Customized use}

\UnderflowSetUp{A,B,C}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} \]

\UnderflowSetUp{u,n,d,e,r,f,l,o,w}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18} \]

\end{document}
```

Here is the complete code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_flavour_var_names_clist
\int_new:N   \g_flavour_vars_pos_MAX_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\UnderflowSetUp}{m}{
  \clist_set:Nn \g_flavour_var_names_clist 
                {#1}

  \int_set:Nn \g_flavour_vars_pos_MAX_int 
              {\clist_count:N \g_flavour_var_names_clist}
}

\UnderflowSetUp{x,y}



\int_new:N \l_flavour_expo_pos_int
\int_new:N \l_flavour_expo_pos_MAX_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\xy}{m}{
% CSV data.
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  
% Let's iterate to do the job.
  \int_set_eq:NN \l_flavour_expo_pos_int {1}
  \int_set:Nn    \l_flavour_expo_pos_MAX_int
                 {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
  
  \int_do_while:nn {\l_flavour_expo_pos_int <= \l_flavour_expo_pos_MAX_int}{
% Which variable?
    \clist_item:Nn \g_flavour_var_names_clist 
                   {\int_mod:nn {\l_flavour_expo_pos_int - 1} 
                                {\g_flavour_vars_pos_MAX_int} + 1}
% Current exponent if not 1.
    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int
                {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist \l_flavour_expo_pos_int}

    \if_int_compare:w \l_tmpa_int = 1
    \else:
      ^ {\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}
    \fi:
% One step further.
    \int_incr:N \l_flavour_expo_pos_int
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
   

\begin{document}

\section{Default use}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6} \]

\[ \xy{3,2,1,1,2,3} \]

\[ \xy{-1,-2,-3} \]

\[ \xy{1,2} \]

\[ \xy{12345} \]

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} \]


\section{Customized use}

\UnderflowSetUp{A,B,C}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12} \]

\UnderflowSetUp{u,n,d,e,r,f,l,o,w}

\[ \xy{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @projetmbc!  May I ask if you could make a version that allows users to specify both the variables and the exponents?  Like this:  \varname{x1, x2, ..., xn}  (to specify the variables as x1, x2, ..., xn in that order) and then   \newxy{e1, e2, ..., en}  will generate x1^e1 x2^e2 ... xn^en --- the key is that #variables = #exponents, but n could change.  Bonus:   print xi instead of xi^1 if ei=1.   Extra Bonus:  Don't print xi^0  if ei=0.   THANKS!

Comment: @underflow You should ask a new question with the API you want to use. It would be easy to implement.

Comment: I just did  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684466/macro-for-printing-monomials  Thanks!