# Macro for printing monomials

Tags: latex3

This is a follow-up to my previous question [How to convert a sequence of integers into a monomial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684352/how-to-convert-a-sequence-of-integers-into-a-monomial/684373?noredirect=1#comment1698091_684373)

**Question 1.** Is it possible a macro that takes two inputs

- varname:   `{ x1, x2, ... , xn }`
- exp:       `{ e1, e2, ... , en }`

and generate the `TeX` output

`x1^{e1} \cdots xn^{en}`

Example:

- varname = `{ a, B, \gamma, \Delta }`
- exp     = `{ -3, 0, 1, 4 }`

would give

`a^{-3} B^0 \gamma^1 \Delta^4`

*Note: the two input lists have the same positive length, but this length can change from one instance to another.*

**Question 2.**  The same basic macro as above, with the following additional features.

- If one of the `ei` is `1`, print `xi` instead of `xi^1`.
- Do not print any term whose exponent is zero.

So in the example about, this time we want

`a^{-3} \gamma \Delta^4`

*Note: Question 2 **does not replace** Question 1; there are instances where I need to display every term of the monomial, including ones with exponents 0 or 1.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\seq_mapthread_function:nn`

The command `\monomial` takes the variables and the exponents; it traverses the two lists (stopping when one of them ends) and does the job for every pair of items.

The *-variant makes every variable and exponent to be printed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\monomial}{smm}
 {
  \underflow_monomial:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__underflow_monomial_var_seq
\seq_new:N \l__underflow_monomial_exp_seq
\bool_new:N \l__underflow_monomial_show_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \underflow_monomial:nnn
 {
  \group_begin:
  \bool_set:Nn \l__underflow_monomial_show_bool { #1 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__underflow_monomial_var_seq { #2 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__underflow_monomial_exp_seq { #3 }
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN
    \l__underflow_monomial_var_seq % first seq
    \l__underflow_monomial_exp_seq % second seq
    \__underflow_monomial_print:nn
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__underflow_monomial_print:nn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #2 }
   {
    {0}{\bool_if:NT \l__underflow_monomial_show_bool { #1^{0} }}
    {1}{#1\bool_if:NT \l__underflow_monomial_show_bool { ^{1} }}
   }
   { #1^{#2} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\monomial{ a, B, \gamma, \Delta }{ -3, 0, 1, 4 }$

$\monomial*{ a, B, \gamma, \Delta }{ -3, 0, 1, 4 }$

\end{document}
```

The corner case when every exponent is zero is not considered (you get nothing in this case).

[image]

With

```
$\monomial{x_1,x_2,x_3}{e_1,e_2,e_3}$
```

you get

[image]

Comment: The corner case when every exponent is zero is not considered must give `1`.

Comment: @projetmbc I ***know***, but this doesn't seem really important in this case.

Comment: Can I edit your question withe management of the all zero case via a global boolean?

Comment: Can you confirm that using `group_begin: ... \group_end:` is a safe way to work with local variables?

Comment: @projetmbc I'm not going into the check for all zero exponents, unless explicitly requested by the OP; printing something that one *knows* is the trivial monomial doesn't seem a real use case. But yes, grouping is a safe way.

Comment: @egreg  This is super awesome; I'm sure others will find it very useful.

Comment: @projetmbc   You are right about the all-exponent-zero edge case (or even when all-exponent-are-1), but these are non-issues in my scenario.  Thanks for bringing this up and for suggesting that I post this as a separate question.

Comment: @underflow I made a tiny (but relevant) fix. Look for the case when the exponent is 1.

Answer (score 5):

What can we do with TeX primitives only:

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\monomial#1#2{\def\mnL{}\mnA #1,\end #2,\end}

\def\mnA #1,#2\end #3,#4\end{\addto\mnL{\mnB{#1}{#3}}%
   \ifx^#2^\mnL \else \afterfi{\mnA #2\end#4\end}\fi
}
\def\mnB#1#2{\ifcase#2\or #1\else #1^{#2}\fi}

$\monomial{ a, B, \gamma, \Delta }{ -3, 0, 1, 4 }$
```

If you want to print all exponents, define:

```
\def\mnB#1#2{#1^{#2}}
```